# Fourier image correlation is likely to be wrong

Tags: image-processing, image, computer-vision

I have images of two identical ellipses, which differ by the orientation.

[image: ellipse1]

[image: ellipse2]

I want to obtain the difference angle between them by means of phase corelation method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation).

In order to make rotation (and, possibly, scaling) additive I transform those images to Log-Polar coordinates and obtain two images of identical size:

[image: log1]

[image: log2]

It is clearly seen that images differ from each other by shift along the $y$-line.

I implement the phase correlation in the following way:

```
four1 = Fourier[ImageData[log1]];
four2 = Fourier[ImageData[log2]];

R = (four1 * Conjugate[four2])/Abs[four1 * Conjugate[four2]];

r = Chop[InverseFourier[R]];
```

The resulting image looks suspiciously incorrect

[image: correlatedImage]

According to the method, there should be one peak present (or several). The peak should be located at the point $(x, y)$, where $y$-component determines the angle of rotation by the following relation:

$$angle = y * 180.0 / image.cols$$

It is clear that such vertical "peak-bands" spreading along the sides should not be present. So, I guess I'm doing something wrong.

**UPD:** The main problem here was the ignorance about the 
    Image
function. As NikiEstner noticed in the comments below, this function does not rescale pixel values, so any pixels with values more than 1 will appear white.

So, the correct way of finding the angle is the following:

```
Position[r/Max[r], Max[r/Max[r]]]
{{49, 1}}
```

The actual rotation angle in degrees is
$$49 \times 180 / 86 = 102$$

**This angle appears to be wrong.**

By the way, phaseCorrelate method in OpenCV determined the rotation angle correctly.

Comment: `Image` doesn't scale the array you pass in. Any value > 1 will be displayed as white. If you look at `Image[r/Max[r]]`, you'll see what you expect: One single bright pixel, and a few darker spots around it.

Comment: @NikiEstner
did not know this, thank you.

Comment: Do you want to provide an answer (e.g. further describing the method) that makes this question more useful for other users? Otherwise I would vote to close this question, as it seems like a simple mistake

Comment: @NikiEstner do you mean to add your answer into my question? Yes, I am going to do it today. Now I am stuck why the angle obtained via this method seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @NikiEstner or maybe I was wrong about the angle. Unfortunately, I do not know precise value. I will add your comment into my post.

Comment: I mean that a question on this site should be useful to other users, too. Right now, I don't think it is. That's why I'm voting to close. If you look at `Image[RotateRight[ImageData[log2], 48]]`, you'll see that it's perfectly aligned with `log1` - so the correlation part seems to be working fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: can you show in your question how you tranformed the original image into log-polar coordinates

Comment: @magma I used OpenCV function logPolar, see e.g. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html